# How to support multiple output languages for comments in doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have some comments, which are written in multiple languages, here are the comments:

```
/**
 * \brief Norwegian
 *
 * Norwegian Bokmål.
 *
 */
```

I use doxygen to generate the docuementation. In the doxygen configuration file, the value for OUTPUT_LANGUAGE is English.

In the generated documentation, "Bokmål" is not displayed corrected, which is:

```
Norwegian Bokm�l.
```

Does anybody know a way to display "Bokmål" correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a matter of setting the right input encoding in the configuration file, i.e.

```
INPUT_ENCODING = ISO-8859-1
```

Default encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: And if you save the extra pages in UTF-8 then the similar problem would come. (text pages would have different encoding with you comments in code) So maybe save the pages, e.g. "extra_doc.md", also in ISO-8859-1 format